# Intuitionist Logic Question

Tags: logic, propositional-calculus, intuitionistic-logic

Show that it is not the case that if ⊨ ¬(A ∧ B) then ⊨ ¬A or ⊨ ¬B.

Consider the formula ¬(p∧¬p).

Replace A with p and B with ¬p.

Validity: this is deﬁned as truth preservation over all worlds of all interpretations. The intuitionist logical consequence is |=I

Comment: what is your question?

Comment: What exactly it means to "show" this is going to depend on how exactly you've defined your system. Intuitionistic logic is a bit more delicate in this regard than classical logic.

Comment: My question is how do I show that the disjunction of ⊨ ¬A or ⊨ ¬B is false in order to make it not the case if ⊨ ¬(A ∧ B) then ⊨ ¬A or ⊨ ¬B. I can prove that  ⊨ ¬(A ∧ B) is the case through trees but do know how to prove the consequent is false. The problem is asking how can one prove that the antecedent  ⊨ ¬(A ∧ B) is true and the consequent ⊨ ¬A or ⊨ ¬B is false.

Comment: I'm going to repeat my comment from your previous (now deleted question): we can't possibly answer this question unless you tell us your definition of $\models$. If $\varphi$ is a sentence, under what conditions is $\varphi$ true? I believe this is also what Ian is getting at in his comment.